# Displaying pdf document in MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I've read posts that say the the `MFMailComposeViewController should display your attached PDF if its a 1 page document but for some reason my PDF is always showing up as just an icon.  I want it to display the PDF since its only 1 page.  The PDF seems to be fine since I can send the email and I can open it in the mail app or on my computer.

Is this not enabled by default in iOS 6.0 or later or is there something im missing?

```
MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;

// create the message body.
NSMutableString *body = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

// add the user name to the email body.
[body appendFormat:@"Name: %@", userName];

// add the pdf to the email.
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
[controller addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"application/pdf" 
                                   fileName:@"test.pdf" 
                           includeExtension:YES]];

// add the body string to the email body.
[controller setMessageBody:body isHTML:NO];

// show the email controller.
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: It works for me. Perhaps the issue is because your message body is not HTML.

Comment: Hi @rmaddy, I changed it to isHTML:YES and I'm still getting the same issue.

Comment: You need to actually provide HTML content in the message body. This means you must include `<html><body>...</body></html>` around the rest of the HTML content. Simply passing `YES` to the `isHTML` parameter isn't enough.

Comment: That didn't work either.

Comment: I just tested this in my own app on an iPad with iOS 6.1.3. I generated a 1-page PDF and chose to send it via email with `MFMailComposeViewController`. The PDF showed inline. One thing though - I just realized that in this case, I never call `setMessageBody:isHTML:`. As a test, see what happens if you don't add a message body.

Comment: I took out the setMessageBody:isHTML call and its still not showing up inline for me...